# Installing GeoIP module for latest NGINX for Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, devops, geoip

I am trying to create a docker image which contains a nginx service with GeoIP module. As far as I tried, running `apt-get install nginx` with any flags doesn't help to include the `--with-http_geoip_module` module in the nginx installed. Therefore, I tried to installed it from the nginx source

```
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development -y \
&& echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/development/ubuntu xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get build-dep nginx -y \
&& cd /opt \
&& mkdir tempnginx \
&& cd tempnginx \
&& apt-get source nginx \
```

and so on and so on

The GeoIP doesn't work as it should, as I tried to put it on the log as like this :

nginx.conf

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
geoip_city /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat;

log_format main '$remote_addr - [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $bytes_sent $request_time $upstream_response_time'
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio" '
        '"$geoip_region" "$geoip_city" "$geoip_city_country_code"';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

}
```

The log will just print those GeoIP parameters as "-"

Any idea why it doesn't work? The Nginx version should be the latest one.

-- edit --

Add the result from running nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.13.3
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx-1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx-1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx-1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx-1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx-1.13.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

modules

```
modules
path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules
http_ssl_module
http_stub_status_module
http_realip_module
http_auth_request_module
http_v2_module
http_dav_module
http_slice_module
http_addition_module
http_geoip_module
http_gunzip_module
http_gzip_static_module
http_image_filter_module=dynamic
http_sub_module
http_xslt_module=dynamic
stream_ssl_module
stream_ssl_preread_module
mail_ssl_module
module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx
1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx
module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx
1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx
module
module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx
1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx
module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx
1.13.3/debian/modules/nginx
module=/opt/tempnginx/nginx
1.13.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Comment: Try using the `openresty/openresty` image instead and see if it helps

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say that I would like to use ubuntu base image. The one I am using now is ubuntu:16.04

Comment: Do you see any error in logs about the module? Also make sure the data paths you specified exist inside the container and not blank files

Comment: As far as I see, there is no error in nginx error log. The file exists inside the container as well. Btw, I added the result from nginx -V for your reference

Comment: Try to see if the openresty images works for you or not. That may shed some light on to the issue. Also try to the run the container on host network and see if the same thing happens. add `--net=host`in your docker run command

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the installation is working, and I just realised that I tried to access it from localhost, which means the IP becomes unresolved. After trying on remote host, the GeoIP module works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The module `ngx_http_geoip_module` is already installed on all official docker image. You can check the Dockerfile there: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/mainline or look inside your container at: `/usr/lib/nginx/modules`.
To use the module you need to enable it in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` by adding:
`load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;` in the first lines.

Warning: `nginx -V` does not seams to mention the module even when it is enabled.

You can find the databases here: https://www.miyuru.lk/geoiplegacy and need to copy the files in your container.

A simple config looks like this for your `nginx.conf`:

```
--- stuff
http {
--- stuff
geoip_country /etc/nginx/country.dat; # the country IP data
geoip_city /etc/nginx/city.dat; # the city IP data

log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]'
              '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent'
              '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
              '"$request_time" "$upstream_connect_time"'
              '"$geoip_city" "$geoip_city_country_code"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;
--- other stuff
}
```

Make sure your `$remote_addr` is a real ip and not a local one (depending on your networking config).
If `$remote_addr` is a local address, what's in front of nginx might set the header `X-Forwarded-For` with the real address. In this case using the module `ngx_http_realip_module` we can replace the local address with the real one like so (this specific case is for traefik):

```
set_real_ip_from  172.24.0.2;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

This is to be put before our geoip config.